# Why my LibreCAD does not show the design

Tags: libreoffice, cad

[image: Why]

Here is the console:

```
$ sudo librecad 
RS_DEBUG::setLevel(3)
RS_DEBUG: Critical
RS_DEBUG: Errors
RS_DEBUG: Warnings
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

Am I missing any dependency packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you're extremely far zoomed out, based on the coordinates shown.

Try typing `za` while in Librecad to zoom all. This should zoom so that the entire outline fits on screen.

Furthermore. DO NOT run Librecad as root. There's no reason to do that.

Comment: You are correct. I'm not sure whether I was extremely zoomed out/in, but now I can see the design :)  `za` does not work for me. What I did was clicked: `View` --> `Autozoom` and wow the design finally comes out haha